# If $\int f=0$ and $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, then $f=0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> If $\int f=0$ and $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, then $f=0$ a.e.

I let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a finite measurable set.

I try to break this into two cases:

Case 1: If $f(x)=0$ on $E$, then we are done (as trivially $f=0$ a.e.).

Case 2: If $f(x) > 0$ on $E$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k m(E_k)=0$. I think I can prove by contradiction here. Can I assume $f \not= 0$, which means $f > 0$ in this case? Then, do I need to show that $\int_E f > 0$, which would contradict the hypothesis of $\int_E f = 0$. Is this a good approach to this?

Comment: Why do you assume that $f$ integrable $\implies$ $f$ bounded? $x \mapsto 1/\sqrt x$ is integrable near $0$.

Comment: Intuition sucks sometimes, resulting in awful conjectures. That being said, I do not need to make use of simple functions here, do I?

Comment: Not sure you need it but it would probably work.

Comment: The negation of your result would be $f >0$ *on a set $E$ of measure $>0$*

Comment: @dragon : Simple functions is probably the best way to go, honestly. Think about this intuition : if you assumed $f$ continuous, your first reflex would be to pick a point where $f$ is not zero, pick a little $\delta$-neighborhood around that point and get a lower bound on the integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another way to do it which doesn't explicitly make use of approximating $f$ by simple functions.

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let

$$E_n = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}\right\} = f^{-1}\left(\left[\frac{1}{n}, \infty\right)\right).$$

Note that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n = f^{-1}((0, \infty))$. If $f$ is not zero almost everywhere, then $m(f^{-1}(0, \infty)) > 0$ so there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m(E_n) > 0$. Now note that $f \geq \frac{1}{n}\chi_{E_n}$ so $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f\, dm \geq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{1}{n}\chi_{E_n}\, dm = \frac{1}{n}m(E_n) > 0.$$

Therefore, if $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f\, dm = 0$, $f = 0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: I mean, you are approximating $f$ with a simple function. It's just a very raw approximation, i.e. $f \ge 1/n \chi_{E_n}$. I simply used another one. But still this proof is more analogous to the classical proof in the continuous/Riemann integral case. +1

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: I suppose you are correct. I should have said that $f$ is not being approximated by a sequence of simple functions.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that if $f$ is a positive measurable function, there exists an increasing sequence of simple functions $\varphi_n = \sum_{i=1}^{m_n} a_{n,i} \mathbb{1}_{E_{n,i}}$ which converges to $f$, where $\mathbb 1_{E_{n,i}}$ denotes the indicator function and the $E_{n,i}$'s are measurable sets. In the case of $f$ positive, we have
$$
\int f \, d\lambda = \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \int \sum_{i=1}^{m_n} a_{n,i} \mathbb{1}_{E_{n,i}} = \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \sum_{i=1}^{m_n} a_{n,i} \lambda(E_{n,i}) = 0. 
$$ 
In particular, since all the $a_{n,i}$'s are strictly positive, for any $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ we have
$$
0 \le a_{n_0,i} \lambda(E_{n_0,i}) \le \sum_{i=1}^{m_{n_0}} a_{n_0,i} \lambda(E_{n_0,i}) \le \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \sum_{i=1}^{m_n} a_{n,i} \lambda(E_{n,i}) = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \lambda(E_{n_0,i}) = 0.
$$
It follows that $f \neq 0$ on a set of measure zero, namely on the set
$$
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \bigcup_{i=1}^{m_n} E_{n,i}.
$$
(This is a countable union of sets of measure zero, thus has measure zero.)

Hope that helps,