# $\int f(x)h(x)d x = \int g(x)h(x)dx$ for any bounded integrable function $h$ if and only if $f(x)=g(x)$

Tags: integration

How to show that $\int f(x)h(x)d x = \int g(x)h(x)dx$ for any bounded function $h$ if and only if $f(x)=g(x)$. The "if" part is clear. How to show the only if part?

Comment: It seems that the "if" would be the easy direction

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Isn't it sufficient that $f(x) = g(x)$ almost everywhere?

Comment: @ZachGershkoff in some contexts, the "almost everywhere" is implicit.  On the other hand, her could be talking about Riemann integration.

Comment: I think more clarifications are required, like definition domain for f, g, h, the fact that f is identical g etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** let $A = \{x : f(x) > g(x)\}$ and consider $h = \chi_A.$

---

the hint reflects the kind of argument that you might want to use, you need to be a little bit careful here and there since you only want to consider admissible $h$'s. Also, unless you have some regularity on $f$ and $g$, you cannot conclude that the equality holds everywhere.

---

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220718/if-int-f-0-and-fx-ge-0-for-all-x-in-mathbbrd-then-f-0-a-e) is a reading I would suggest.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$
\int f(x)h(x)\,dx - \int g(x)h(x)\,dx = 
\int [f(x) - g(x)]h(x)\,dx
$$
The integral on the right is zero for **every** choice of $h(x)$.